# R: Grouping by variable THEN counting/filtering by occurrences of another

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count

I have a data frame of categorical variables and states. For each state, I want to find the most common categorical variable, and filter the rest out.

E.g.

```
1  Alabama   cat_variable_1
2  Alabama   cat_variable_2
3  Alabama   cat_variable_2
4  Alabama   cat_variable_3
```

For Alabama, cat_variable_2 would be the most common - so rows with cat_variable_2 would be all that remains in this data frame under Alabama. This would go on for each state.

```
1  Alabama   cat_variable_2
2  Alabama   cat_variable_2
```

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the variables with max number of occurrence in each each `State`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(state) %>% filter(variable == names(which.max(table(variable))))

#   state   variable      
#  <chr>   <chr>         
#1 Alabama cat_variable_2
#2 Alabama cat_variable_2
```

You can also write this in base R :

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(variable, state, 
           FUN = function(x) x == names(which.max(table(x))))))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[variable == names(which.max(table(variable)))], state]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(state = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"
), variable = c("cat_variable_1", "cat_variable_2", "cat_variable_2", 
"cat_variable_3")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a new df with the combinations you want and then use `dplyr::inner_join` on the original df to only keep those combinations.

```
library(dplyr)

## An example df with two "states" with different most common cat_var.
df <- tibble(
  state = gl(2, 50, labels = c("AL", "NY")),
  cat_var = case_when(
    state == "AL" ~ sample(1:3, 100, TRUE, prob = c(.2, .3, .5)),
    state == "NY" ~ sample(1:3, 100, TRUE, prob = c(.5, .3, .2))
  ),
  y = rnorm(100)
)

## Keeps the cat_var in each state that is most common, giving a df
## with each state--cat_var comb that we can filter against.
state_vars <-
  df %>%
  count(state, cat_var, sort = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()

## Use `inner_join` to only keep those comb in `state_vars`.
inner_join(df, state_vars, by = c("state", "cat_var"))
```